# Python IMAP4 append fails silently

Tags: python-3.x, imap, imaplib

When appending a message to a folder that doesn't exist, there is no error thrown. It's hard to imagine that this is intended, what am I doing wrong?

```
mailbox = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(host="foo")
mailbox.login("foo", "bar")
try:
    mailbox.append("DOES_NOT_EXIST", '', imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), str(mail).encode("utf-8"))
except:
    # Expecting to fail here, but it doesn't
    # Message doesn't show up in any other folder either (expectedly)
```

Comment: Well, [it's documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imaplib.html#imap4-objects): that call to .append(...) returns "NO" and you discard the return value.

Comment: You're totally right, no idea why I didn't see it. Thank you very much for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

As rightfully stated in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55178142/python-imap4-append-fails-silently#comment97095027_55178142), this is actually intended behaviour indeed and [documented](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/imaplib.html#imap4-objects).

> Each command returns a tuple: (type, [data, ...]) where type is usually 'OK' or 'NO', and data is either the text from the command response, or mandated results from the command.

One way to catch the error therefore is:

```
status, data = mailbox.append("DOES_NOT_EXIST", '', imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), str(mail).encode("utf-8"))
if status == "NO":
    # Catch it here
```